# return indexes of all regex occurrences in string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I obtain an array of the indexes (or positions) all occurrences of a regexp in a string?

```
example_string= "hello how are you?
```

I would like to obtain the array [1,12] for regexp `/e/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one approach to get an array of indexes of matches:

```
example_string = "hello how are you?"

example_string.enum_for(:scan, /e/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }

# => [1, 12]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

This is a variant of @Zoren's excellent answer:

```
example_string = "hello how are you?"

example_string.gsub(/e/).with_object([]) { |_,a| a << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
 #=> [1, 12]
```